# django orm - annotate / aggregation (avg) in subquery

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-aggregation, django-database-functions

I have this model:

```
class UserMovieRel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("register.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey("Movie", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="users")
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10)], null=True, blank=True
    )
    advice = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = UserMovieRelManager()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.user} - {self.movie} (rating: {self.rating or 'n/a'})"

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["user", "movie"], name="user_movie_unique"),
        ]
```

I'm trying to get the avg rating for each movie in this way:

```
avg_ratings = UserMovieRel.objects.filter(movie_id=OuterRef("movie_id")).exclude(rating__isnull=True).annotate(avg_rating=Avg("rating"))
UserMovieRel.objects.annotate(avg_rating=Subquery(avg_ratings[0]))
```

but it fails:

```
ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.
```

I've tried also with aggregation:

```
UserMovieRel.objects.annotate(
    avg_rating=Subquery(
        UserMovieRel.objects.filter(
            movie_id=OuterRef("movie_id")
        ).aggregate(
            avg_rating=Avg("rating")
        )["avg_rating"]
    )
)
```

but I've got the same error.

any help on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Movie.objects.annotate(avg_rating=Avg('users__rating'))
```

the reason we use `users` is because that is the value for the `related_name='users'`, but does not make much sense.

You can rename it to:

```
from django.conf import settings

from django import models


class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(
        'Movie', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews'
    )
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10)],
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    advice = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = UserMovieRelManager()
```

and thus query with:

```
Movie.objects.annotate(avg_rating=Avg('reviews__rating'))
```

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Rel` suffix. A model is not a relation or table, it is stored in a relational database as a table, but even then it has extra logic like validators, managers, etc.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).